# JPA Entity - How to update a child entity field based on its parent field

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jpa-2.1

I am currently stuck on an issue of updating a parent entity field and getting the update to cascade to all its children's fields.

Here is an example of what I am trying to accomplish:

**User**.java

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TINYINT(1) default false")
    private Boolean archived = Boolean.FALSE;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
    private Set<Invoice> invoices = new HashSet<Invoice>();

    // Setters & Getters
}
```

**Invoice**.java

```
@Entity
public class Invoice{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TINYINT(1) default false")
    private Boolean archived = Boolean.FALSE;

    @ManyToOne(mappedBy = "invoices")
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    private User user;

    // Setters & Getters
}
```

When I update the archived value to `true`. I want all the invoices to also be updated to `true` as well.

I.E

```
    public Boolean archiveUserById(Integer id) {

        User user= entity_manager.find(User.class, id);

        Boolean result = false;

        if(auction != null) {
            // This should cascade to all the invoices as well and update their archived fields to true as well
            user.setArchived(true);

            try {
                entity_manager.getTransaction().begin();
                entity_manager.merge(auction);
                entity_manager.getTransaction().commit();
                result = true;
            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

I've tried using `cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST` and `@JoinTable(....)` with all the referenced columns, but they are still failing to update the fields correctly.

To clarify is there a way to update a child's field through its parents' update with a Cascade effect?

Thank-you for the help.

## **EDIT**

To clarify my question, I am trying to add a constraint cascade effect when a field on the parent entity is updated to reflect on the child entity's same field. I am trying to avoid any logic within the Entity itself. Is there a way to do this through annotations only?

Something to the same effect as this:

```
ALTER TABLE `child` ADD CONSTRAINT `childs-archived-mirrors-parent`
FOREIGN KEY (`archived`, `parentId`)
REFERENCES `parent`(`archived`, `id`)
ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: why you couldn't use smth like `public void setArchived(boolean archived) { invoices.forEach(inv -> inv.setArchived(archived)}`?

Comment: I understand the notion of trying to solve this in the ORM layer, but I strongly recommend you consider implementing this as a *DB trigger*. (in which case you'd need to make sure the child-collection is re-loaded after UPDATE)

Comment: @ZhenyaM

I'm trying to avoid introducing any business logic within the Entity and keeping it as a POJO. I have tried the method of just looping through each invoice as you have stated within a Service class, but I am just trying to find another solution for updating multiple child objects based on its parents state.

Comment: @Simon, Thanks for the answer. But unfortunately, a DB trigger wouldn't be the best tactic for this scenario. I do not want to abstract the update logic from the code base, if possible.

I will edit my question to better clarify what I am trying to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help.

I ended up finding a solution. I created a custom foreign key definition that will cascade any update on the archived field to its child entities.

Below is how I accomplished that.

```
@Entity
public class Invoice{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;

    @Column(nullable = false, columnDefinition = "TINYINT(1) default false")
    private Boolean archived = Boolean.FALSE;

    @ManyToOne(mappedBy = "invoices")
    @JoinColumn(nullable = false, foreignKey = @ForeignKey(foreignKeyDefinition = "FOREIGN KEY (archived, user_id) REFERENCES user(archived, id) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE CASCADE"))
    private User user;

    // Setters & Getters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding `@PreUpdate` method on parent where you manually change children inside the list.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I do not want to involve any logic within the entity itself if possible. I will update my question to better clarify what I am trying to achieve.